# Laravel Query Builder: get all has many related row in key value format in side main row

Tags: mysql, laravel

Product table

```
"id",
"sort_order",
"name",
"visible",
"description",
```

Product Property table

```
"product_id",
"key_name",
"key_value"
```

The response I need from the query builder

```
[{
"id": 1,
"sort_order": 1,
"name": "Samosas",
"visible": 1,
"description": null,
"property": {
    "{key_name}": "{key_value}",
    "{key_name}": "{key_value}",
    "{key_name}": "{key_value}",
}
}]
```

or atleast i can achive it like elequent with relation

```
[{
"id": 1,
"sort_order": 1,
"name": "Samosas",
"visible": 1,
"description": null,
"property": [
    {
        "product_id": 1,
        "key_name": "categories",
        "key_value": "Starter"
    },
    {
        "product_id": 1,
        "key_name": "print_order",
        "key_value": "1"
    }

]}]
```

i tried in elequent it can be done but for query builder how to achive that form sql side?

i tried by joining them:

```
DB::('products')->join('product_properties', 'product.id', '=', 'product_properties.product_id')->get()
```

Thanks

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aecTzSbP5UcLkoCGrvhqoX/0 now the homework is to convert in into query builder..

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by first fetching the main rows, then iterating over them to fetch and format the related rows.

```php
$results = DB::table('products')->get();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $properties = DB::table('product_properties')
        ->where('product_id', $result->id)
        ->pluck('key_value', 'key_name');

    $result->property = $properties;
}

return $results;
```

Or you can eager load:

```
$products = \App\Models\Product::with('properties')->get();

$products->transform(function ($product) {
    $properties = $product->properties->pluck('key_value', 'key_name');
    $product->property = $properties;
    unset($product->properties);
    return $product;
});

return $products;
```

Comment: lazy loading with `foreach`? it will save db calls if you fetch the list of products first along with its properties using eloquent then re-format the resulting array..

Comment: Yes but for large number of products it will take time to complete, to reduce time id wanted to shift from Elequent to Query Builder. Thanks

Comment: @muntasir a simple join can't make json the way you wanted, internally laravel's `with` runs 2 queries and then map the objects in memory. you might need to resort to a [`jsonarrayagg`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) black magic.

Answer (score 1):

**way 1**: add a json column to database and set the properties in this column. in migration of products table add `$table->json('property')->nullable();` and in product model add cast to array for this column `protected $casts = ['property' => 'array'];` and add product in database like this:

```
[
       "id": 1,
       "sort_order": 1,
       "name": "Samosas",
       "visible": 1,
       "description": null,
       'property' => [
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value2',
            'key3' => 'value3',
        ]
]
```

then after retrieving the products return like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "p1",
    "content": null,
    "price": 100,
    "count": 0,
    "property": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    },
},
```

**way 2**: you can add new attribute for product model and use it in product resource:
attribute in product model

```
function getMyPropertyAttribute()
{
    return $this->property->pluck('value', 'key');
}
```

and use it in product resource like: `'my_property'=> $this->myProperty,`